# Calculating area in polar coordinates with definite integrals

Tags: definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

Find the area of the following regions given in polar coordinates ($r$=radius, $t$=angle) 
A) $D={(r;t) : 1 + cos(t) \le r \le 3cos(t)}$
B) $D={(r;t) : r \le |2cos(5t)|}$

In A) I solved the inequality $1 + cos(t) \le 3cos(t)$ keeping in mind that $r$ must be bigger than 0 and $t \epsilon [0;2 \pi ]$ and got that $t \epsilon [0; \frac{ \pi}{3}]U[ \frac{5 \pi }{3};2 \pi]$.
Then I found the area of $3cos(t)$ between 0 and $\frac{ \pi}{3}$ (which I called $Ar_2$), and between $\frac{5 \pi }{3}$ and $2 \pi$ (which I called $Ar_2')$. After that, I did the same thing but with $r= 1 + cos(t)$, and I called the areas $Ar_1$ and $Ar_1'$ respectively.

Then, I computed $(Ar_2 - Ar_1)+(Ar_2' -Ar_1)$ to get the total area the one that I had to calculate. Is it ok?

In B) what should I do? Should I solve $-2cos(5t) \le 2cos(5t)$ and compute the same that in A?

Comment: It always comes in handy to graph the region of interest. This should help you obtain your limits of integration.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the area that you are interested in looks like:
[image]

Were the lines represent the values $t$ for which $r=0$: for instance $t=\pi/10$ and $t=3\pi/10$ in the first quadrant. Notice that, in the first quadrant:

$$|2cos 5t|=
\begin{cases}
2cos 5t &\text{ if} & t \in[0,\pi/10]\cup[3\pi/10,\pi/2]\\
-2cos 5t &\text{ if} & t \in[\pi/10,3\pi/10]
\end{cases}
$$

This means that we can compute the desired area as follows:

$$A=\int\int_D r\, dr\,dt$$

Given our drawing, for the first quadrant this is equal to:

\begin{align}
A&=\int_0^{\pi/10}\int_0^{2cos 5t} r\, dr\,dt+\int_{\pi/10}^{3\pi/10}\int_0^{-2cos 5t} r\, dr\,dt+\int_{3\pi/10}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{2cos 5t} r\, dr\,dt\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/10}(2cos 5t)^2 dt+\frac{1}{2}\int_{\pi/10}^{3\pi/10}(-2cos 5t)^2 dt+\frac{1}{2}\int_{3\pi/10}^{\pi/2}(2cos 5t)^2 dt\\
&=\pi/2
\end{align}

This means that the total area given by the four quadrants is given by $4\cdot A=2\pi$. Similarly notice that each petal has area $\pi/5$ and there are 10 petals.

Comment: Why did you write $cos^2 (2t)$? Wouldn't it be $cos^2 (5t)$? Also, I don't understand why $1.5$. And why did you just take the positive part of $|2cos(5t)|$?

Comment: Just corrected the graph and explained some intermediate steps, please let me know if it is clearer.